# eloquent orm or sql statement

Tags: mysql, orm, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to get total debit, total credit and available balance for day from transactions table.

I have tried this so far...

```
        SELECT
        sum(credit),
        sum(debit),
                sum(credit) - sum(debit) as remaining_balance
                FROM transactions
    WHERE user_id = 2
group by created_at;
```

Its not giving correct results.

SQL FIDDLE....

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25a27/2

I want to have results like bank/paypal statement, for example...

```
Date  - Debit - Credit - Balance
05/11 - 2.20  -        - 7.3
05/10 -       - 1.5    - 9.5
05/06 -       - 2.5    - 8
05/05 -       - 5.5    - 5.5
```

I am using laravel eloquent orm, so if its possible by ORM it would be great suggestion for me. thanks

Comment: Which transaction description are you trying to show for the entire day?

Comment: what is your expected result ? can you update the question and post that.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using a fairly simple JOIN;

```
SELECT DATE(a.created_at) date, a.debit, a.credit, 
  SUM(b.credit - b.debit) balance
FROM transactions a
LEFT JOIN transactions b
  ON DATE(a.created_at) >= DATE(b.created_at)
GROUP BY DATE(created_at)
ORDER BY DATE(created_at) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d14046/2).

The problem here is that the JOIN condition and the GROUP BY condition use a value calculated on a field instead of using the field itself. This will limit the use of indexes and make the query really slow for large amounts of data.

A solution would be to add a separate DATE field which holds the date of the transaction. This will allow the JOIN/GROUP BY to work directly on a field and it can use indexing much more efficiently.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you update your query with SUM of credit and sum of debit instead of using balance, as balance will not be updated much, its just for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your `GROUP BY` is in the wrong place</strike>

Grouping by a day works like this:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  sum(credit),
  sum(debit),
  sum(credit) - sum(debit) as remaining_balance, 
  txn_description,
  DAY(created_at)
FROM transactions
WHERE user_id = 2
GROUP BY DAY(created_at);
```

More functions are available at the [DateTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) documentation

Comment: sorry that's just typo. i have also tried this but not giving correct results as you can see in sql fiddle.